# How to solve the Cast error problem according to my code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend, mongoose-web-server

I have actually made an error handler to handle the status code errors and display a message accordingly but it is giving me the following error:

```
const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "636e6099887452407c7551e" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Product"
    at model.Query.exec (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4891:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4990:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: '"636e6099887452407c7551e"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '636e6099887452407c7551e',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new BSONTypeError (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\bson\lib\error.js:41:28)
      at new ObjectId (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\bson\lib\objectid.js:67:23)
      at castObjectId (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1201:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1648:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1636:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1612:20)
      at cast (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:342:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (D:\Abdullah's Data\Ecommerce Project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:5319:12),
  valueType: 'string'
```

error.js file is like the following

```
const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorhandler");

module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
    err.statusCode = err.statusCode || "500";
    err.message = err.message || "Internal Server Error";

    res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        success: false,
        message: err.message
    })
}
```

Error handler file is something like

```
class ErrorHandler extends Error{
    constructor(message, statusCode){
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;

        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    }
}

module.exports = ErrorHandler;
```

And I am using it inside the productController.js file as

```
exports.getProductDetails = async (req, res, next)=>{
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

    if(!product){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Product not Found", 404));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        product
    })
}
```

If I manually use the req.body method and define the error by myself then it is working fine but if I use error handler then it is causing problems.

Comment: can you write nodejs code of CastError class?

Comment: Your `value` does not look like it is a `string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer` as the error mentions

Comment: How can I resolve it? I actually tried many things and one of them worked for me I don't know which one. I know it's funny but it's what happened for me